# JS - Расширения Google Chrome. Проблема с загрузкой дома

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Есть проблема с написанием расширения.

Через расширения хром я внедряю свой js файл в ДОМ, но на определенном сайте подгружаются фреймы и когда я хочу навешать события на определенный элемент, но он еще не загрузился в фрейме. Каким образом я могу проверить загрузку всего дом элемента через расширения хром?

DOMContentLoaded - не работает.

load - Так-же

В файле manifest.json

"run_at": "document_end" - так-же не работает.

Я решил вопрос через setTimeout на 4 сек но в большинстве случаях он так-же не работает, так как дом не подгрузил те самые элементы.

Надеюсь правильно задал вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Можешь использовать такую штуку:

```js
const keepFrameHot=async()=>{
    // check, if exist
    if($('#myInjectedCode').length > 0)return false;

    // inject here

    // for example
    $('body').append(`<style id="myInjectedCode">
        body{
            background:#232323!important;
        }
    </style>`);
    // or another example
    $('body').append(`<script id="myInjectedCode">
        (()=>{alert('Hello there');})();
    </script>`);
};

keepFrameHot();
setInterval(keepFrameHot, 1000);
```

**Будь внимателен** `$(селектор-ид).length` всегда **1** возвращает